# Convert Oracle SQL query to Azure SQL query

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-update, azure-sql-database, sql-insert

I have a pretty long Oracle SQL query that needs to be compatible for Azure SQL. I am new to both database types. Here is query:

```
MERGE INTO studies
    USING dual
    ON (study_id = :study_id)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (study_id, study_date)
        VALUES (:study_id, :study_date)
```

I am not sure `USING dual` would work. I read some solution saying that `USING dual` is not necessary in SQL Server.

I really appreciate if you can explain what this query means and how I can translate this for Azure SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Oracle `merge` query has just a `WHEN NOT MATCHED` clause and no `WHEN MATCHED`, so basically that's `insert` and `not exists`:

```
insert into studies(study_id, study_date)
select x.*
from (values(@study_id, @study_date)) as x(study_id, study_date)
where not exists (select 1 from studies s1 where s1.study_id = x.study_id)
```

This is logically equivalent to the original Oracle query.

As for your original question: SQL Server does supports its own flavor or [`merge` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), whose syntax is different than Oracle. You would rewrite the Oracle `merge` as:

```
merge studies as s
using (values(@study_id, @study_date)) as x(study_id, study_date)
on (s.study_id = x.study_id)
when not matched 
    then insert (study_id, study_date) values(x.study_id, x.study_date)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Question about the original oracle sql command. Does it mean that with the given `:study_id`, if that study_id doesn't exist on `studies` table, I am inserting a row. Is that it?

Comment: @JonathanHagen: yes, that's what the Oracle query you showed does.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, but one more question.. what does `x.*` mean?

Comment: @JonathanHagen: this relates to the derived table that contains the values, which is aliased `x`.