# How do I convert given SQL query to SQL Server query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, sql-insert, database-migration, sql-merge

I have a SQL query I need to understand and translate to SQL Server query. Here is SQL query:

```
MERGE INTO study_event
    USING dual
    ON (study_id = :study_id)
       WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
       INSERT (study_id, study_date)
       VALUES (:study_id, :study_date)
```

From how I understand, this means **if study_event table doesn't have given study_id, I am inserting row to study_event table with given study_id and study_date.** Is this correct?

I am trying to create SQL Server query that will do the same operation. From stack overflow, this is what I found:

```
INSERT INTO study_event(study_id, study_date)
SELECT x.*
FROM (VALUES(@study_id, @study_date)) as x(study_id, study_date)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM studies s1 WHERE s1.study_id = x.study_id)
```

I think I understand this query but I am not sure what `SELECT x.*` means. Would this query work and what does x.* mean?

Comment: SQL Server supports `MERGE` as well. Though having a `MERGE` without a `WHEN MATCHED` seems a little odd for this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` refers to the alias that the `values()` subquery creates, here:

```
FROM (VALUES(@study_id, @study_date)) as x(study_id, study_date)
```

This creates a derived table with one row and two columns `study_id` and `study_date`.

So basically `x.*` gives you the entire row from `x`, which contains the two original parameters to the query, `@study_id` and `@study_date`.

Disclaimer: [I answered the original question!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63696229/10676716)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't understand at the time but I didn't wanna keep bothering you :) I appreciate it. Now I understand!